# Uninitialized Constant Where a String should Be in link_to do Block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following HAML:

```
  =link_to "#", :data => {:'reveal-id' => "philly"} do
    .large-4.small-6.columns.neighborhood-box{:style => "background-image: url('philly-low.jpg')"}
      =Philadelphia
```

Which is outputting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Philadelphia
```

And I have no idea why. It seems like all of my brackets are properly closed and I'm following the link_to do format, yet it seems to be attempting to interpret Philadelphia not as a string to be output but a reference to a template.... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display plain text, just use no tags:

```
Philadelphia
```

Or if you want a Ruby string:

```
= "Philadelphia"
```

The code you wrote is telling Ruby to expect a constant/class name instead of a string.